Some sites don't work properly on Android, but they work on Windows
I'm using an old smartphone as router and, although its connection is working flawlessly on my PC, when I try to access some sites on Android phones, they find some issues to load.
These sites either take at least 10 seconds to start loading, or they don't load at all. What's funny is that when they work, once they load I can navigate through that domain with no issues; only the first connection takes too long.
About 40% of the sites work fine, but 60% present this issue. It's probably some sort of security measure that finds issues with that phone as router, but Windows is able to deal with it, while Android isn't.
For instance, sites that work fine:

theguardian.com
wtatennis.com
eurogamer.net

Sites that have the issue:

bbc.com
atptour.com
pcgamer.com

When I use a proper router with a 3G modem, this problem doesn't happen. But I need this phone as router because its reception is much better. It's a tricky situation, but I tried to be as detailed as possible.
I would like to know if there's some trick to bypass this issue. I tried a user agent switcher on my phone, but it didn't work.

If it is only the first connection a DNS problem could be the cause.

@Robert: I had tried changing the DNS server before to dns.google but it hadn't worked. But after your comment I decided to try a new DNS server, and it worked with one.one.one.one Thank you!

After the comment by @Robert about a possible DNS problem, I decided to try new DNS servers to see if it could solve the issue. I had tried the Google DNS before, but it had not worked.
Changing the DNS server to one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1) worked for me.
